# How to change the background color of the title-bar in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, frontend

```
<Style x:Key="WindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Gray1}" />
</Style>
```

I am trying to change the background of the titlebar in my wpf application using 
style in the app resource. The above style is not working. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you must rewrite window's ControlTemplate,because by default window's title bar background is bound to SystemColor.That's why you change system theme, you will get new title background.